# Ionic 3 keyboard hides input field when in landscape mode

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an Ionic app that must be in landscape mode. When a user tap on an input field to type, the keyboard comes up, so the user can only see the header, footer and the keyboard, thus the user can't see what he is typing. I saw on native apps when I do the same thing, the keyboard comes up with a separate textbox, which will be perfect for my Ionic app. How can I do it in Ionic? Here are some screenshots:

## The screen in landscape mode before typing

[image]

## The screen when typing starts

[image]

## The screen on native apps when typing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use scrollAssist: true for IonicModule.

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
  scrollAssist: true
}),
```

Comment: Thanks for your message. I tried this, but the outcome is still the same

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Looks like the only way to fix this is to hide the `header` and `footer` when keyboard is showing and show `header` and `footer` when keyboard is hiding. I also had to remove some `margins` so that the focused `input` is at the top. Here's my code I added in the `app.component.ts`:

```
keyboard.onKeyboardShow().subscribe(() => {

    let headers = document.querySelectorAll("ion-header"); //Get all headers
    headers[headers.length - 1].setAttribute("style", "display: none"); //Hide ACTIVE header

    let footers = document.querySelectorAll("ion-footer"); //Get all footers
    footers[footers.length - 1].setAttribute("style", "display: none"); //Hide ACTIVE footer

    let contents = document.querySelectorAll("ion-content"); //Get all content
    contents[contents.length - 1].querySelector("div.scroll-content").removeAttribute("style"); // Remove styling from content (margins)
  });

  keyboard.onKeyboardHide().subscribe(() => {
    let headers = document.querySelectorAll("ion-header"); //Get all headers
    headers[headers.length - 1].removeAttribute("style"); //Show ACTIVE header again

    let footers = document.querySelectorAll("ion-footer"); //Get all footers
    footers[footers.length - 1].removeAttribute("style"); //Show ACTIVE footer

    let contents = document.querySelectorAll("ion-content"); //Get all content
    contents[contents.length - 1].querySelector("div.scroll-content").setAttribute("style", "margin-top: 56px; margin-bottom: 56px;"); //Set styling again (margins)
  });
```